# Generator of singular homology of sphere with coefficients in $A$

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology

We know that $\widetilde H_n(S^n;A)\cong A$ for all $n\geq0$ and all abelian groups $A$.

Because $\widetilde H_n(S^n;\mathbb Z)\cong\mathbb Z$, it has a generator, say $\sigma$.

Now, why does it hold that $\sigma$ is also a generator of $\widetilde H_n(S^n;A)$, so that $\widetilde H_n(S^n;A)=\{a\sigma:a\in A\}\cong A$?

Comment: Did you mean to refer to homology groups both with and without the tilde on top of notation in your question?

Comment: @coffeemath thanks for pointing it out, I meant with the tilde (so the reduced homologies). For all cases but $n=0$ this doesn't matter that much

Comment: You have to make precise what you mean.  If $\sigma \in \widetilde H_n(S^n;\mathbb Z)$, then $\sigma \notin \widetilde H_n(S^n;\mathbb A)$.